# How to handle Unsupported use of op_LOAD_CLOSURE encountered?

Tags: python, numba

This is my MWE:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit   
def solve(n):
    count = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=int)
    res = np.array([0], dtype=int)

    def search(sz=0, max_val=1, single=0, previous=None):
        nonlocal res
        if sz == 4 * n:
            res[0] += 1
            return
        if single and count[0] < 2 * n:
            count[0] += 1
            search(sz + 1, max_val, single)
            count[0] -= 1
        for i in range(1, max_val + 1):
            if i != previous and count[i] < 2:
                count[i] += 1
                search(sz + 1, max_val + (i == max_val and max_val < n), single + (count[i] == 1) - (count[i] == 2), i)
                count[i] -= 1
 
    search()
    return res[0]

for i in range(1, 6):
    print(solve(i))
```

This gives:

```
NotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
Unsupported use of op_LOAD_CLOSURE encountered
```

What's the right way to get this to work with numba? The code runs correctly, if slowly, if you remove the @njit line.

Comment: Just don't use closures? Also why are you jit-ing the *outer* function which doesn't do anything of note?

Comment: @Masklinn I misunderstood and thought that jit-ing the outer function would also jit all the functions it contained.

Comment: @Simd: It does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put `@njit` to the inner function:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


def solve(n):
    @njit
    def search(count, res, sz=0, max_val=1, single=0, previous=None):
        if sz == 4 * n:
            res[0] += 1
            return
        if single and count[0] < 2 * n:
            count[0] += 1
            search(count, res, sz + 1, max_val, single)
            count[0] -= 1
        for i in range(1, max_val + 1):
            if i != previous and count[i] < 2:
                count[i] += 1
                search(
                    count,
                    res,
                    sz + 1,
                    max_val + (i == max_val and max_val < n),
                    single + (count[i] == 1) - (count[i] == 2),
                    i,
                )
                count[i] -= 1

    count = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=int)
    res = np.array([0], dtype=int)
    search(count, res)
    return res[0]


for i in range(1, 6):
    print(solve(i))
```

---

Running this script using `time` command:

```
andrej@MyPC:/app$ time python3 script.py
1
28
1816
180143
23783809

real    0m3,818s
user    0m0,015s
sys     0m0,004s
```

For comparison, without the `@njit`:

```
andrej@MyPC:/app$ time python3 script.py
1
28
1816
180143
23783809

real    1m42,000s
user    0m0,011s
sys     0m0,005s
```

Comment: There's not much point to having the function be an inner function, since you had to remove the closure variable usage anyway. I think putting `njit` on an inner function may even require re-JITting the inner function every time you call the outer function.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, probably restructuring the code in this case would be better (put the inner function out of `solve()`, or using `cache=True` at least)

Comment: cache=True didn't give any speedup for me. In fact it seems to have slowed it down a little.

Comment: @Simd `cache=True` means, that the result of compilation is written to the file (so `numba` doesn't have to recompile the function again - this is time-consuming task). If you invoke the function only once, you won't see a benefit. It depends how you use/invoke the compiled function. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html?highlight=cache#cache

Comment: @AndrejKesely I guess in the case we call it 5 times which isn't enough to be worthwhile.

Answer (score -1):

Numba nopython-jitted functions [cannot have](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#inner-function-and-closure) recursive inner functions:

> Numba now supports inner functions **as long as they are non-recursive** and only called locally, but not passed as argument or returned as result.

Write your code without the recursive inner function. (Alternatively, since the restriction only applies to inner functions *inside* jitted functions, you could technically just jit the inner function... but you'd have to remove all use of closure variables, so there's no point having it be an inner function at that point.)